# How convert very long string to double in portable C

Tags: c, atof, strtod

I want to convert a very long string of numbers to a double in a portable way in C.  In my case, portable means that it would work in Linux and Windows.  My ultimate goal is to be able to pack a string of numbers into an 8-byte double and fwrite/fread to/from a binary file.  The number is always unsigned.

I am using this string to pack a 4 digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit day, 4 digit HH:MM, 1 digit variable, and a 10 digit value.  So, trying to pack 23 bytes into 8 bytes.

I have tried all of the standard things:

```
char myNumAsString[] = "1234567890123456789";

char *ptr;
char dNumString[64];
double dNum;


dNum = atol(myNumAsString);
sprintf(dNumString, "%lf", dNum);

dNum = atof(myNumAsString);
sprintf(dNumString, "%lf", dNum);

dNum = strtod(myNumAsString, &ptr);
sprintf(dNumString, "%lf", dNum);

sscanf(myNumAsString, "%lf", &dNum);
sprintf(dNumString, "%lf", dNum);
```

And none of these work; they all round off the last several numbers.  Any portable way to do this?

Comment: `double` is not arbitrary-precision. If your input has too many significant digits, no algorithm will be able to convert it to `double` without losing precision.

Comment: @EOF, so is there a way to do this using a long or long long or something else?

Comment: There are uncountably infinitely many real numbers between 0 and 1. There are less than 2 to the power of 64 `double`s. There *may* be (but probably *aren't*) something like 2 to the power of 128 `long double`s. No, `long double` cannot represent all real numbers.

Comment: Take a look at https://gmplib.org/

Comment: It's difficult to suggest a solution without more information about the intended use of the very long string of numbers.

Comment: I am using this string to pack a 4 digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit day, 4 digit HH:MM, 1 digit variable, and a 10 digit value.  So, trying to pack 13 bytes into 8 bytes.    I edited question with this info.

Comment: @user994179 Ah, very good.  This problem is well understood. I suggest looking at the asctime family of functions in libc for your solution and creating a structure with a 'struct tm' member, a variable member and a value member.  Using fwrite/fread to pass data between hosts with (possibly) different architectures and operating systems is perilous ( see XDR and JSON as solutions to that problem ).

Comment: Last time I checked `4+2+2+4+1+10 = 23`. If it was actually a 13 digit number, you could store it in a `double`, or even a `uint64_t`. But a 23 digit number doesn't fit in either.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the addition, it's 23 not 13.

Comment: So the consensus seems to be there is no way to do this.  So instead I will split the number into 2 parts, and store as 2 ints.  To do this, I just need to subtract 1900 from the year and do something similar for the time, and everything fits, in a nice, portable way.  The max time value is 16:00, so I can just subtract 900.  This saves me two bytes.

Comment: See [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?hl=en) which serializes messages into binary that can be read on a platform that supports it.

Comment: Disagree with "the consensus seems to be there is no way to do this."  Simply pack the timestamp portion into a serialize number of minutes as step 1 - this is portable.   The rest is easy.

Comment: the easiest way is to use the 'strtod()' function  it will convert a string to double.  or, if you need more digits, use the 'strtold()' function however, that will pack the string into a long double (16 bytes)

Comment: @user3629249 OP's input consist of 23 decimal digits.  Typical windows `long double` is at best 21 decimal digits of precision.  A simple conversion to `long double` will fail to maintain 23 digit distinctiveness.  Check the value of `LDBL_DIG` on systems of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take advantage that part of the string is a timestamp and not any set of digits.

With 60 minutes, 24 hours, 365.25 days/year, `y` years, a digit and 10 digits, there are `60*24*365.25*y*10*pow(10,10)` combinations or about `5.3e16 * y`

An 8-byte, 64-bit number has `1.8e19` combinations.   So if the *range* of years is 350 or less (like 1970 to 2320), things will fit.

Assuming unix timestamp, and OP can convert a time string to `time_t` (check out `mktime()`) ....

```
time_t epoch = 0;  // Jan 1, 1970, Adjust as needed.

uint64_t pack(time_t t, int digit1, unsigned long long digit10) {
  uint64_t pack = digit1 * 10000000000 + digit10;
  time_t tminutes = (t - epoch)/60;

  pack += tminutes*100000000000;
  return pack;
}
```

Reverse to unpack.

---

Or a more complete portable packing (code untested)

```
#include <time.h>
// pack 19 digit string
// "YYYYMMDDHHmm11234567890"
uint64_t pack(const char *s) {
  struct tm tm0 = {0};
  tm0.tm_year = 1970 - 1900;
  tm0.tm_mon = 1-1;
  tm0.tm_mday = 1;
  tm0.tm_isdst = -1;
  time_t t0 = mktime(&tm0);  // t0 will be 0 on a Unix system
  struct tm tm = {0};
  char sentinal;
  int digit1;
  unsigned long long digit10;
  if (strlen(s) != 4+2+2+2+2+1+10) return -1;
  if (7 != sscanf(s, "%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d%1d%10llu%c", &tm.tm_year,
          &tm.tm_mon, &tm.tm_mday, &tm.tm_hour, &tm.tm_min,
          &digit1, &digit10, &sentinal)) return -1;
  tm.tm_year -= 1900;
  tm.tm_mon--;
  tm.tm_isdst = -1;
  time_t t = mktime(&tm);

  double diff_sec = difftime(t, t0);
  unsigned long long diff_min= diff_sec/60;
  return diff_min * 100000000000 + digit1*10000000000ull + digit10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save some bits as soon as you know the numbers can not be any value.

- HH:MM : 0<=HH<=23 <32 : 5 bits, 0 <= MM <= 59 <64 : 6 bits
- DD : 1 <= DD <= 31 < 32 : 5 bits
- mm (month) : 1 <= mm <= 12 < 16 : 4 bits

So instead or 8 bytes you only need 20 bits that is less than 3 bytes.

- YYYY : do you really need to accept any year between 0 and 9999 ??? If you could limit the interesting part to just 2 centuries, 8 bits would be enough.

So a full date could stand in as little as 4 bytes instead of 12.

But if you want to add to that a 10 digit number + 1 variable, that would not stand in the 4 remaining bytes because the greatest uint32_t is 4294967295 enough for any 9 digit number and about half of 10 digit numbers.

If 32 years were enough, you could represent up to 34359738360 that is 10 digits and a variable taking values 0 1 or 2

Lets see that more precisely; the transformations would be:

```
uint64_t timestamp;
uint8_t minute(uint64_t timestamp) { return timestamp & 0x3f; }
uint8_t hour(uint64_t timestamp) { return (timestamp >> 6) & 0x1f; }
uint8_t day(uint64_t timestamp) { return (timestamp >> 11) & 0x1f; }
uint8_t month(uint64_t timestamp) { return (timestamp >> 16) & 0x1f; }
uint8_t year(uint64_t timestamp) { return orig_year + ((timestamp >> 20) & 0x3f); } // max 64 years
uint64_t ten_digits(uint64_t timestamp) { return orig_year + ((timestamp >> 26) & 0x7FFFFFFFF); }
uint8_t var(uint64_t timestamp) { return (timestamp >> 61) & 0x7); } // 8 values for the one digit variable
```

If you can accept only 4 values for the one digit variable, end part becomes:

```
uint8_t year(uint64_t timestamp) { return orig_year + ((timestamp >> 20) & 0x7f); } // max 128 years
uint64_t ten_digits(uint64_t timestamp) { return orig_year + ((timestamp >> 27) & 0x7FFFFFFFF); }
uint8_t var(uint64_t timestamp) { return (timestamp >> 61) & 0x3); } // 4 values for the one digit variable
```

You could even save some bits if you computed an absolute number of minutes since an epoch, but computations would be much more complexes.